# can gzip only store a file like zip and not compress it?

Tags: compression, gzip, deflate

Is it possible for gzip to not compress a file? What happens in that case? Does the archive still contain a DEFLATE stream? I need to handle this special case in my program.

Comment: Why not just test this (e.g. by using the `-1` or `--fast` option with already compressed data)?

Comment: Whoever decide to cast final re-open vote make sure to edit in all necessary information for the question that OP decided to post on Meta - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346135/question-closed-as-belonging-on-super-user-but-is-a-programming-issue before casting the vote.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov As requested. user1095108, I hope I did justice to the question. I suppose you know how to roll back if you disagree with the edit I made.

Comment: I'd like to ask the downvoters to undo their votes, which were mainly due to the Meta effect. We now know that the OP not only did prior research, but actually _consulted authorative sources_ before asking here. The question now shows this, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if the file is not compressible for example if it's already compressed, gzip will make a stored block which contains the source data with some header and trailers appended.

You can make your own non-compressed stream if that's needed.  RFC 1951 Sections 3.2.3 and 3.2.4  describe how it's done.

A Deflate stored block is basically a single byte whose value is 0x00 or 0x01 (BTYPE=00 and BFINAL=0,1), followed by 4 bytes of LEN and NLEN followed by your actual data.  LEN is the number of data bytes (2^16=64KB) and NLEN is one's complement.  If you have more than 64KB, you have to do this multiple times. The last block should have the BFINAL bit set to 1.

Finally, you will have to prepend all of this with a gzip header RFC 1952 (assuming it is a GZIP stream, otherwise check RFC 1950 for ZLIB). The header contains filename, timestamp etc.  It's couple hours of work on your part --most time will be spent understanding the spec.

Comment: I understand the gzip spec, but I don't know deflate.

Comment: Gzip contains Deflate.  Gzip is just a wrapper of a header and trailer around Deflate.